# Optimizing postgresql maintenance statements on psql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In a reddit-like app (called `Links`) I maintain, users post hyperlinks and others can then publicly reply under the said links. The former is saved in a postgresql 9.3.10 table called `links_link`, the latter in a table called `links_publicreply`.

My task is to:

1. Delete all `link` objects created in a 30 day time window.
2. Delete all `publicreply` objects associated with objects in (1), and created within a 45 day time window.

Here's how I just did that for one time-window from 2016:

```
begin;
  delete from links_publicreply where submitted_on >= timestamp'2016-07-23 01:01:00' and submitted_on < timestamp'2016-09-07 01:00:00' and answer_to_id in (select id from links_link where submitted_on >=timestamp'2016-07-23 01:00:00' and submitted_on < timestamp'2016-08-23 01:00:00');
  delete from links_link where submitted_on >= timestamp'2016-07-23 01:00:00' and submitted_on < timestamp'2016-08-23 01:00:00';
commit;
```

Notice I'm querying `links_link` exactly the same way *twice*. I.e. once each in both `delete` statements. Now in Django ORM (of which I'm a native), I would have optimized this via first getting all the required `links_link` object ids separately, and then using them in all proceeding statements. How do I optimize that in the `psql` command line?

---

The most pertinent advice I've seen [is in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552441/4936905), but it seems the `with` clause has to be inside the SQL statement it's being called in.

In other words, the following wouldn't work would it?

```
BEGIN;
  DELETE FROM links_publicreply
    WHERE submitted_on >= timestamp '2016-07-23 01:01:00'
        AND submitted_on < timestamp '2016-09-07 01:00:00'
        AND answer_to_id in (
            SELECT id
            FROM links_link
            WHERE submitted_on >= timestamp '2016-07-23 01:00:00'
                AND submitted_on < timestamp '2016-08-23 01:00:00'
    );
    DELETE FROM links_link
    WHERE submitted_on >= timestamp'2016-07-23 01:00:00'
        AND submitted_on < timestamp'2016-08-23 01:00:00';
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The most pertinent advice I've seen is in this SO answer, but it seems the with clause has to be inside the SQL statement it's being called in.

Yes, you can use a modifying `WITH`, i.e. a CTE that deletes from one table and returns the `id` values to the rest of the query, so they can be used to delete from the second table:

```
WITH
  links_link_deleted AS
    ( DELETE FROM links_link
        WHERE submitted_on >= timestamp'2016-07-23 01:00:00'
          AND submitted_on < timestamp'2016-08-23 01:00:00'
      RETURNING id
    ) 
DELETE FROM links_publicreply
  WHERE submitted_on >= timestamp '2016-07-23 01:01:00'
    AND submitted_on < timestamp '2016-09-07 01:00:00'
    AND answer_to_id IN
        ( SELECT id
          FROM links_link_deleted
        )
 ;
```

> In other words, the following wouldn't work would it?

That would work but it would be two statements.

Comment: I can wrap this around `begin;` and `commit;` like one typically does, correct?

Comment: @HassanBaig of course. If it's the only statement in the transaction, you could also run it in autocommit mode.

Comment: Well with autocommit, I wouldn't have a clean way to `rollback` like I can in a transaction right? I normally run everything in a transaction because of that.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Also, if you want the id values of the deleted rows from both tables, you could rewrite this with 2 CTEs and a final SELECT that returns all of them. (I can edit if you need that)

Comment: Well, thanks for the offer, I'd love to see that in the solution too. Although I won't be using it in this particular maintenance scenario - but you just introduced me to CTEs, so one more practical example is awesome!